# XAdES internally detached signature

Tags: xml, digital-signature, xades4j

I want to create a file that contains multiple independent signatures referencing the same data. I want the data to be stored **in** the output XML file, as a sibling to `ds:Signature` elements, like below (only with multiple `ds:Signature` elements):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<internally-detached>
  <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:CanonicalizationMethod 
         Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
      <ds:SignatureMethod 
         Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
      <ds:Reference URI="#data">
        <ds:DigestMethod 
          Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
        <ds:DigestValue/>
      </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue/>
  </ds:Signature>

  <document Id="data">
     <title>title</title>
     <author>writer</author>
     <date>today</date>
     <content>
        <para>First paragraph</para>
        <para>Second paragraph</para>
     </content>
  </document>
</internally-detached>
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759193(v=vs.85).aspx
(I am aware that the site does not mention XAdES standard).

I tried to apply this to a valid enveloping XAdES signature and putting the referenced `ds:Object` node outside the `ds:Signature` element, but the verification software returns an error (referenced node was not found), and the xades4j verification module fails after encountering the `</internally-detached>` tag.

**Is an internally detached signature possible with XAdES?** If so, how can I achieve that?

I know that multiple signatures are possible when the data is stored in a separate file: each signature's SignedProperties element must contain SignedDataObjectProperties with ObjectReference, and the URI in SignedInfo's Reference element should point to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's certainly possible with XAdES signatures, since they are also "regular" XML signatures.

I'm not sure what you mean by "xades4j doesn't even allow a root node other than `ds:Signature`"; your objective can be easily achieved.

Assuming you have the base XML document without any signatures (either from a file or created using DOM APIs):

```
<internally-detached>
  <document Id="data">
     <title>title</title>
     <author>writer</author>
     <date>today</date>
     <content>
        <para>First paragraph</para>
        <para>Second paragraph</para>
     </content>
  </document>
</internally-detached>
```

Having this and, lets say, 2 differently configured instances of [XadesSigner](http://luisgoncalves.github.io/xades4j/javadocs/1.3.1/reference/xades4j/production/XadesSigner.html), you can do something like:

```
XadesSigner signer1 = ...;
XadesSigner signer2 = ...;
Document doc = ...; // your base XML
Element signaturesParent = doc.getDocumentElement();

SignedDataObjects objs = new SignedDataObjects(new DataObjectReference("#data"));
signer1.sign(obj, signaturesParent);
signer2.sign(obj, signaturesParent);
```

Just beware that you need to [define the "data" element's Id attribute as its XML ID](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/blob/master/src/main/java/xades4j/utils/DOMHelper.java#L177).

This should produce a document similar to:

```
<internally-detached>
  <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  ...
  </ds:Signature>
  <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  ...
  </ds:Signature>
  <document Id="data">
     <title>title</title>
     <author>writer</author>
     <date>today</date>
     <content>
        <para>First paragraph</para>
        <para>Second paragraph</para>
     </content>
  </document>
</internally-detached>
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately my verification software does not show the generated signature as a valid one (after merging it with the base XML document of course) - "certificate integrity error". What I meant by "xades4j doesn't even allow..." is that the xades4j verification module returns error for my manually edited signature file (I have updated the question to be more specific). I am more interested in the final output signature file structure than how to do it in xades4j (I have to implement the signature myself), maybe you could post an example?

Comment: Weird; it should be valid. What do you mean by "merging"? You should just need to serialize the DOM document on the end and use the resulting file for verification. As for the final output, I've updated the answer. If you need details on the XAdES structure, take a look on xades4j tests, which contain samples.

Comment: OK, I did that (and the output file is the same as when I "merged" it - I put the whole file together by hand ;). The certificate's serial number is written as a negative number - and that is (I think) why the signature is invalid.

Comment: If that's the case it's probably a problem on the verification software. The original question is addressed. Let me know if I can help with further issues.

Comment: @bmscicho ["The serial number MUST be a positive integer assigned by the CA to each certificate."](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.2) I've seen software fail on this before, it's a valid check - if maybe a bit strict. But for an RFC a MUST is a MUST.